# Showing that $\limsup_{\nu \to \infty} \frac{|a_\nu|}{|a_{\nu + 1}|} = 0$ implies $R = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Consider the complex power series $$\sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty a_\nu(z - z_0)$$
with radius of convergence $R$. We defined the radius of convergence by $$R := \sup_{t \geq 0} \{(|a_\nu|t^\nu)_{\nu \in \mathbb{N}} \text{ is bounded}\}$$ Now I want to show that if $$T := \limsup_{\nu \to \infty} \frac{|a_\nu|}{|a_{\nu + 1}|} = 0$$ then $R = 0$. I already showed that in the case $T > 0$ we have that $T \geq R$. Any hint?

Comment: If you have already shown that $R \leq T$ for  any positive $T$ then you can expand the definition of the limit for $T$ and show that $R$ is less than any positive number, thus $R$ could only be equal to zero.